# Geodatabase compression schedule

Tags: esri-geodatabase, arccatalog, data-management

Is there a way to schedule a GDB on an SQL server to automatically compress once a day? As of right now I need to remember to open catalog and compress a Geodatabase manually everyday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ArcToolbox > Data Management Tools > Geodatabase Administration there is a tool Compress.

If you run this tool (once) and copy python snippet from the completed result into a python file, you can schedule a batch file to run that python file.

You can schedule any ArcToolbox tool this way.

Python file:

```py
import arcpy
arcpy.Compress_management(r"c:\connections\gdbconnection.sde")
```

Batch file:

```
python.exe c:\script\mycompress.py
```

Schedule this batch file in Windows Scheduled Tasks.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress the database using `sdeversion` command line tool (you have to fill in with your properties):

```
sdeversion -o compress [-N] -u <ArcSDE_Admin_user_name> 
                       [-p <ArcSDE_Admin_user_password>] 
                       [-q] [-i <service> | <port#> | <direct connection>] 
                       [-s <server_name>] 
                       [-D <database_name>]
```

You may also wish to run the `sdemon -o kill -t all` command to disconnect all pending connections if you face problems with locks on DB tables while executing script from above.

```
sdemon -o kill -t <{ all | pid }> 
                  [-p <ArcSDE_admin_password>] [-N]
                  {[-i <service> | <port#> | <direct_connect_info>]
                  {[-s <server_name>] | [-H <sde_directory>]}
                  [-u <user_name>] [-p <user_password>] [-D <database_name>]
```

And you can put this scripts to a **batch file on server** and schedule to run this script at your prefered time and frequency.
In example if you're in control of Windows server you will set this script to work with **Task Scheduler**, on Linux you have **cron job**.

Comment: @Midavalo Thanks for your comment! Command line tools are supported up to geodatabases version 10.2.2. At version 10.3 they are no longer available and migrating workflows to ArcPy is recommended, as I read here http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012433 - good to know before upgrading